# Unhandled Rejection (Error): expecting a value for non-nullable variable: stime of type: time! in variableValues

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am getting this error in the code.Can u please help me this. This is my code.
My mutation

```
const ADD_SCHEDULE = gql`
  mutation MyMutation($date:date!,$etime:time!  ,$stime:time!,$title:String!) {
    MyMutation(date: $date, etime: $etime, stime: $stime, title: $title) {
      affected_rows
    }
  }
`;
```

Create function for creating a schedule.

```
const Create = () => 

    let date,title,stime,etime;
      const[createschedule] = useMutation(ADD_SCHEDULE);
       
       return (
         <div>
        <form 
        onSubmit = {(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            createschedule({variables:{title:title.value, date:date.value ,stime:stime.value,etime:etime.value}});
          }}>
        
          <TextField id="title"   ref={value => title=value}  label="Title" />
       
        
          <TextField
            id="date"
            defaultValue="2017-05-24"
            label="Date"
            type="date"
            ref={value => date=value}
             
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
          />
        
        
          <TextField
            id="stime"
          
            label="STime"
            ref={value => stime=value}
            type="time"
            defaultValue="07:30"
           
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
            inputProps={{
              step: 300, // 5 min
            }}
          />
        
          <TextField
            id="etime"
           
            label="ETitle"
            type="time"
            ref={value => etime=value}
            defaultValue="07:30"
           
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
            inputProps={{
              step: 300,
            }}
          />
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
      
    </form>
        
    </div>
        );
        
        }
    
    
    export default Create
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate problems

- test API using graphiql/playground (and of course query variables) to check required arg/variables format (for custom date/type types/scalars)
- ... then check if your client (react app) sends variables in required format ... explore browsers dev tools network request body - compare it detaily with playground